# sharepoint 2010 3 tier install and configuration queries

Tags: installation

My setup

```
    NLB

WFE1(VM)  WFE2(VM)

APP1       APP2

SQLserver 2008 R2
```

1. installed SQLserver 2008
2. install sharepoint 2010 on **app1**

   - Create and configure the farm
   - run sharepoint congfiguration wizard
3. install sharepoint 2010 on **app2**

   - join to existing  farm
   - advanced setting -- **( do not use this machine to host website)**
   - run sharepoint congfiguration wizard
4. install sharepoint 2010 on **wfe1**

   - join to existing  farm
   - advanced setting -- **( do not use this machine to host website)**
   - run sharepoint congfiguration wizard
5. install sharepoint 2010 on **wfe2**

   - join to existing  farm
   - advanced setting -- **( do not use this machine to host website)**
   - run sharepoint congfiguration wizard

Now when I want to create a new web application, it gives me only `http://app1`

But I want to create web app and site collection either in `wfe1` or `wfe2`, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you load balanced the WFEs then the web app will exist on both. Infact, the WFEs should hold identical data in terms of the SharePoint environment.

Comment: 1) create a web application and then create a site collection ? so regardless on which server i log on to i can only create a web application on app1 , is it because CA is hosted on app1 and not anywhere else and if i reconfigure wfe1 and wfe2 setting -- advanced setting during install(use this machine to host website) will I be able to create web app on the wfe's ?

Comment: Your web applications will always exist on both web front ends, you cannot configure them to have separate web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by when you create a web app it gives you http://app1... when creating a web app you specify the URL. Do you mean when you create a site collection? Only app1 is available?

Since your WFE are load balanced, you can create a web app using either the NLB address, or use one of the WFE as an address, and then add the NLB as an alternate  address after.

When you add a web app, that site is created on all servers running the web application services, which is probably your two WFEs and one App server, running Central Admin. Then you use DNS to control which server(s) are actually being hit, in your case DNS should point to your NLB.

Comment: I am doing something wrong during the install  step1 install SQserver 2008 , step 2 install sharepoint on app1 <--- is this the right step ?

Comment: step 1 is pretty straight forward. step 2, i always start on the app server that I will use to access central admin.